# Overlapping third party stylesheets

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I'm using google's css package in my google script app:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
```

However, I would like to use my own css for styling table elements. The only problem is that google's css package contains css for table elements, and it seems to be overwriting my custom css except it's not doing it consistently. For example, on my laptop the web app uses my table css and for my desktop it uses google's css package (both running windows 10 using chrome--although the desktop's chrome might not be updated). Is there any way to ignore google's css for tables or even to know for sure which styling will supersede the other? What if I were using two third party stylesheets that both defined css for tables? How could I specify which one I wanted for a specific selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to overwrite styling of other CSS files make sure to include you CSS file after the ones you want to override. And learning about CSS specificity helps alot.

EDIT:
I think this link may help you: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/